# generating same event from window when using pattern?

Tags: esper

I am using esper and when I query my named window with timer:interval(10 sec) i get the same event duplicated after every 10 secs. I doesn't outputs other events present in the window.

here is the EPL
on pattern[every timer:interval(20 sec)] select DeviceIP, parent , child, Supress, Status from testZabbixProblem"

Answer (score 0):

The engine outputs all rows in one call to the listener and delivering all rows at once as an array and not just one row.